# Unable to test unstable_useBlocker with data router

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, react-router-dom

I have implemented unstable_useBlocker in some of my components the hook need to implement the newest version of routers with the data api. After that all my tests with the hooks failed because the useBlocker hook throw an error if you don't wrap the component with the good provider.

> Error: useBlocker must be used within a data router.  See https://reactrouter.com/routers/picking-a-router.

I didn't found any way to wrap only the tested component with the RouterProvider I need. I can't just mock the useBlocker hook because I need to validate if the component behavior with the said hook act as expected (that the history haven't changed).

So I was wondering if you guys have found a way to wrap your components with the newest **react-router-dom** router to make your tests.

I found a solution. I have this code in my unit test:

```
const navigator = createMemoryHistory();
const router = createMemoryRouter([{}]);

const component = render(
    <Router location={navigator.location} navigator={navigator}>
        <UNSAFE_NavigationContext.Provider value={{ navigator, basename: '', static: false }}>
            <UNSAFE_DataRouterContext.Provider value={{ navigator, basename: '', router: router, static: false }}>
                <TestedComponent />
            </UNSAFE_DataRouterContext.Provider>
        </UNSAFE_NavigationContext.Provider>
    </Router>
);

act(() => navigator.push('/new-path'));

...
```

then I validate if something happen based on my expected behavior in the hook. Unfortunately nothing happen. The blocker callback is never called.

Answer (score 3):

I have fixed it adding `unstable_useBlocker` mocks

```
 jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
  
  unstable_useBlocker: () => {
    return {
      state: 'blocked',
      reset: jest.fn(),
    }
  },
}))
```

Comment: Are you able to test a scenario where useBlocker supposed to block the navigation with this mock?

Comment: @AnthonyCollin-Nadeau havent tested this, but you can play with `state` option maybe.